# is it possible to bring back the reverted changes

Tags: git

The title must be so confusing coz I didn't know how to say in short. So I made changes to many files, then I commited it. Then I realized I was in wrong branch, so while reverting it, I accidentally did it twice resulting in my whole changes in all the files being lost.RIP. So is there a way I could retrieve those changes or do I have to retype all the code frm beginning? I have the commit ID that has all the changes, I noted down before reverting it

used the gui of vs code to revert

Comment: A revert doesn't delete anything; it creates a new commit that undoes the changes implied by another commit. It's not clear what you did "twice". If you, for example, revert HEAD, then revert HEAD again, you should be back to where you started before the first revert, just with all those changes in the history. Since you have the hash for the last "good" commit, you should be able to simply reset the branch head to that commit, but I hesitate to suggest any concrete action without knowing *exactly* what state your repository is in.

Comment: You can simply revert the revert to get the original code. Or you reset your branch to the known good commit. Or you create a new branch from the known good commit. It really depends on your history or your use-case. Example: [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Comment: So when I looked into VS code UI, it actually says 'Undo Commit' and that's the thing I pressed twice. So what it did was 1. It undid my commit with changes, then 2. It rolled back all the changes I made. Now if I do git log, there's no hash of any of those, the only latest on it is the commit ID where I started making those changes

Comment: I used git cherry-pick <good-commt-ID> and made my push. It did the trick for me